# how can we restrict a script for particular users?

Tags: security, google-apps-script

I want my app script to be available for only limited users like myself and my manager, others should not be able to open it or view it.
Can you guys please help me to do that!. Even though the file is shared on a shared drive with the team.

Comment: Is this a Google Apps Script project?

Comment: @Rafa Guillermo 
yes..

Comment: Just checking because the `appscript` tag is actually for Apple Scripts, not Google Apps Script. I've changed your tags for you.